# "Had + object + P.P." Vs "Had + P.P. + object"

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, grammaticality-in-context, style

SOURCE: A game of thrones

> - The breath of man and horse mingled, steaming, in the cold morning air as his lord father ***had*** ***the*** ***man*** ***cut*** ***down*** from the wall and dragged before them.
>
> Is it a kind of a custom and stylish writing  to move an object instead of a verb, and vice verse,  in this sentence ?

Comment: *Had* is used here as a *causative*, and participle is passive: *His lord father caused the man to be cut down [by somebody]*.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Edited so I don't seem to contradict you rather than respond to OP!